# Remove text from <li> on mouseleave event

Tags: jquery

I have an `ul`. When I hover over any `li` in the list, I am doing some stuff, and on mouseleave, I want to do some other stuff. I am still using jQuery.

The problem comes at the end where the mouseleave event would occur. I basically want to undo the .append() that the .hover event performs...

```
//for each li in #mylist...
$('#myList > li').each(function () {

    //get the li content...
    var liName = $(this)[0].innerText;

    //instantiate number
    var number;

    //instantiate formattedNumber
    var formattedNumber;

    //when hover over each li...
    $(this).hover(function () {

        //get a number from the div where liName is found...
        $('.square').each(function () {

            var name = $(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').text();

            if (name === liName) {

                number = $(this).find('tr:eq(6)').find('td').text();

            }

        })

        //format the number...
        formattedNumber = ': ' + number.substring(0, 3) + '-' + number.substring(3, 6) + '-' + number.substring(6, 10)

        //append the formatted number to this li...
        $(this).append(formattedNumber);

        //when mouse leaves the li, remove the formatted number...
    }, function () {

        //this is what I cannot get working. I basically want to do the opposite on mouseleave and remove the just appended text...but leave the initial content of the li in place

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap you appended text in an element so it’s easier to remove it later:

```
//for each li in #mylist...
$('#myList > li').each(function () {

    //get the li content...
    var liName = $(this)[0].innerText;

    //instantiate number
    var number;

    //instantiate formattedNumber
    var formattedNumber;

    //when hover over each li...
    $(this).hover(function () {

        //get a number from the div where liName is found...
        $('.square').each(function () {

            var name = $(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').text();

            if (name === liName) {

                number = $(this).find('tr:eq(6)').find('td').text();

            }

        });

        //create a span and set its text to as format the number...
        formattedNumber = $('<span />').text(': ' + number.substring(0, 3) + '-' + number.substring(3, 6) + '-' + number.substring(6, 10));

        //append the formatted number to this li...
        $(this).append(formattedNumber);

        //when mouse leaves the li, remove the formatted number...
    }, function () {

        //remove the created span
        formattedNumber.remove();

    });

});
```

Comment: Very good Sir/Madam. That helped immensely, and will do moving forward. Thank you very much!

Comment: @m0lochwalker no problem. I’m glad i could help :-)